# Python script(win32com, excel) crashes when I edit another open workbook. Is this the expected behavior, can I prevent this?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

The error looks like this:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 471, i
 __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs))
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None
 0, -2146777998), None)
```

I'm using office 2007

Comment: What's your script look like? Kind of hard to help with only the error message - we need to know what you did to provoke that message!

Comment: I just edited another excel file, it happens with any python script which manipulates excel using win32com

Comment: well since it works for everyon else it must be either your script or your machine.